# Live\ Hotmail email storage

Tags: onedrive, online-storage, outlook.com

Are all mails from Outlook\Live\Hotmail stored in SkyDrive? Because I have around 6000 emails and some contain attachments of around 1 or 2 MB. But my SkyDrive shows that only 0.01 GB is used. Can I please know if the above values make sense and also whether emails are stored in SkyDrive?

Answer (score 1):

Your values are accurate. Your Outlook\Live\Hotmail messages and data are stored on Microsoft servers. Skydrive is a separate service that you have simply by having an Outlook.com account (not always do you have this, many people do). If you have Outlook locally installed on your computer there are ways to save mail on your hard drive, or in Windows 7 and 8 with Skydrive locally installed you can have messages set up to save there.